# Widget stops counting after 1 minute

Tags: swift, widget, widgetkit

I am fairly new to Widget development, and I am trying to make a seconds widget count.

Here is my Timeline provider:

```swift
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SecondsEntry {
        SecondsEntry(date: Date())
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SecondsEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SecondsEntry(date: Date())
        completion(entry)
    }
        
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
            var entries: [SecondsEntry] = []
            
            // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
            
            let currentDate = Date()
            
            for secondOffset in 0 ... 60 {
                let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: secondOffset, to: currentDate)!
                let entry = SecondsEntry(date: entryDate)
                entries.append(entry)
            }
            
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
            completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

If you need anything else, feel free to let me know.

I tried setting secondOffset to a high number, and also changed the for loop to a while loop. Both of those break the widget even more.

Comment: You are adding 60 seconds, that  seems like it would stop after a minute. I don't understand where the comment "five entries" or "hour apart" happens. I see entries, 1 second apart.

Comment: There is a strict budgets with widgets I believe it is a max of 70 timeline reloads a day. Emphasis on max… there is no way to reload the timeline every minute as your code suggests